# How can I get the actual type from a name of the type in string in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the string of a type that I have gotten through reflection:

```
const paramtypes = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, key);
const myParamType = paramtypes[0].name;  // this returned 'Foo' as a string
```

Now, I would like to convert the name of the type which is in a string into an actual Typescript type of `Foo`. I can't possibly do `typeof myParamType` because this would logically give me string.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
const paramtypes = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, key);
const myParamType = paramtypes[0].name;   // this returned 'Foo' as a string

// My objective is to convert the 'Foo' to Foo type that I can use it as a regular type
function myFunc(): typeof myParamType {   // I want the return type to be Foo but it will end up as string
   ...
}
```

How can I get the type from the name of the type in string?

Comment: Can you show a use case where this would be useful?  Since the code that is evaluated at runtime cannot send information back in time to the pre-transpiled TypeScript code, there's no way that you would be able to do anything better than use a union of all possible types that you expect could appear.  But if you could make a short [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), maybe I could suggest something that works for you?  Not sure.  Good luck!